# Can I use sona masoori rice for making dosa?

Tags: indian-cuisine, batter, fermentation

I have been trying to make dosa in the US since 6 months & never got the fermented batter. When searched in seasoned advice I found a similar question asked. 
[How to ferment dosa batter?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/16639/how-to-ferment-dosa-batter)

I have been using correct proportions of rice, urad dal, fenugreek & poha. Even I tried grinding the mixture using soaked urad dal, rice, water and even kept overnight in the oven with lights turned on, but I never got my dosa batter fermented. I have used the same proportions in India and I was successful in making good fermented dosas, but the only difference is that I am using Sona masoori rice for making dosas in the US. I am suspecting that this might be causing a problem , but I am not sure about this and if it is yes, why is it so ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@tcb,  I have successfully used sona masoori rice for dosa batter.

try this method:

Preheat oven to 200 degree F. Then **turn off the oven**. Then put your batter-pot in the oven on a tray.Check after 5-6 hours. If temp are really low outside, and you think it is still not fermenting ,again turn on oven for a couple of minutes and turn off. Batter should be ready in 9-10 hours.