# What to do with fermented lentils?

Tags: fermentation, lentils

3 days ago, I decided to do some brown lentils, so I did a lentil soup with zucchinis and spice (a lot of cumin and cayenne). I didn't have tupperware so I left  it in the pot with the lid.

And this morning, I found out they are fermenting. then is some bubbles and a strong fermenting smell, still a "clean" smell.

I'm not sure what to do, part of me want to throw it away but I don't want to waste it either. Can I save it or maybe use it for something else?

thanks

Comment: There are quite a few dishes that use *raw* fermented lentils (sometimes lentil flour) that is then cooked ... but usually it's only for a day or two, and you're using the yeasts that would've been on the lentils originally.  (you've killed those by cooking, so we don't know what was doing the fermenting)

Answer (score 10):

Throw it away, it's spoiled and probably contains several colonies of foodborne illnesses. Sealing food isn't sufficient to stop it going off, you need to refrigerate it or freeze it.

Comment: Absolutely. Discard, don’t attempt to eat it.

Comment: Yeah! That I did, for safety.

Comment: But I don't think it was spoiled, spoiled food as a bad or rotten smell, this was a really a fermenting smell like bread starter or ginger bug. Beside, I found some recipe with fermented **crush** lentils, so I think there is something here. That tells me that I didn't ask the right question. Anyways, thanks to both of you for the reply.

Comment: Smell is not a good indicator, things can smell just fine but make you very sick.

Comment: There is so much [conflicting advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/16639/59328) on the intentional fermentation of lentils that I would be very wary  of consuming a result that doesn't arise from known ingredients and methods.

Comment: Well put @RobinBetts, fermentation requires control to be safe.