# How long can I store cooked rice in the refrigerator?

Tags: storage-lifetime, rice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How long can I store a food in the pantry, refrigerator, or freezer?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21068/how-long-can-i-store-a-food-in-the-pantry-refrigerator-or-freezer)

I've heard people claim that you could keep cooked rice as long as 10 days or as short as 48hours.

I'm interested in knowing both when the rice starts loosing it's good taste, and when it starts being dangerous to eat it.

Also, does it change according to the rice type?

Comment: well, the only thing said there about rice is that you can keep it 6 month on the shelf, but nothing about cooked rice unfortunately :(

Comment: There are also links to other sites, like http://stilltasty.com/fooditems/index/18723

Comment: Related questions / comments on other answers : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/20937/67 ; http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/10970/67 ; http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/1411/67 ;

Comment: rice loses the tasty as soon as it cools down enough to no longer have gelatinized starch around the granules, and all temp controlled foods should be discarded after ten days (according to servsafe). I personally throw it out after it starts to grow mold, but I do not hold that model up for other people.

Comment: @Brann the question Mien linked says 3-4 days for all cooked dishes. I would agree that it holds for rice too. Food holds longer only if it lacks a factor bacteria need to live. Practically all cooking recipes result in food people find tasty to eat as-is (as opposed to conserving recipes which might end in something too salty or sour for most tastes), and virtually anything humans find tasty as-is is good enough for bacteria.