# Shelf life and preservation of Bánh chưng

Tags: food-safety, food-preservation, vietnamese-cuisine

It's Tết again and I'm about to buy this traditional Vietnamese delicacy. However, since I'm currently trying out a Joylent-only diet, I'll only be able to eat it after a couple of days.

So my questions are:

1. How long can I safely store Bánh chưng in the fridge?
2. Can I preserve it somehow? I've heard that some people boil or freeze it.

**Edit:** I was able to find some information on Wikipedia, which says the following:

After unwrapping, bánh chưng can stay good for several days while a wrapped one can be kept for two weeks.

Unfortunately, the source is not available online, so I cannot verify its reliability and context. This also contradicts some posts on online forums, where people said it can last even several months! Given the composition and moistness of Bánh chưng, I seriously doubt it.

**Edit 2:** My second piece of bánh chưng is now safely waiting in the freezer. I'll edit the question again when I eat it with details about its composition and taste after unfreezing it.

**Edit 3:** It was pretty much as expected - a bit of a freezer burn, but otherwise it was very close to its original form.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How long can I store a food in the pantry, refrigerator, or freezer?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21068/how-long-can-i-store-a-food-in-the-pantry-refrigerator-or-freezer)

Comment: @JasonSchock Not a duplicate, while the first part of the question might be partially answered in the linked question, the second part is very specific to bánh chưng and cannot be answered by it at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How long can I safely store Bánh chưng in the fridge?

It depends on how good the bánh chưng was wrapped (before cooking) and if the bánh chưng is put into the fridge right after cooking and if the bánh chưng is already cut open. 
i assume that you have a halfway eaten bánh chưng. I would treat this case like regular cooked rice. [A post](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/21069/23376) on cooking.SE says that cooked dishes last 3-4 days in the fridge. [StillTasty](http://stilltasty.com/fooditems/index/18723) says 4-6 days. I just asked my mother. She said it will be fine for one week in the fridge if cut. You may have a look at the comments [on the question "How long can I store cooked rice in the refrigerator?"](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/28619/23376)

> Can I preserve it somehow? I've heard that some people boil or freeze it.

Boiling would kill some pathogens. But since the toxins produced by the previously existing pathogens won't be destroyed, the bánh chưng would be still [unsafe](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/34671/23376).

Freezing: I'm a student and hoard such stuff in my freezer :D Regarding food safety freezing is not problem. If you store the bánh for too long and/or don't wrap the pieces tightly enough the bánh will have freezer burn. I ate frozen bánh chưng which has been for more than a half year in the freezer. It tasted fine after steaming. 
After defrosting you should either recook the bánh or steam it. I think you already knew this ;)

> After unwrapping, bánh chưng can stay good for several days while a
>   wrapped one can be kept for two weeks.

I think this statement sound quite plausible if the bánh chưng was wrapped very tightly and was wrapped in many layers statement and is stored in a fridge *right after cooking*. Bonus: The bánh was cooked in a pressure cooker. I guess, it's even sterile for some time o.o

> some posts on
>   online forums, where people said it can last even several months!

I doubt it, too. Did they really said "fridge", not "freezer"? o.o
<sub>(Oh, or their bánh chưng drowned in lard. Lard lasts for a very long time x))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how it's made. Traditionally it is compressed under heavy weights after cooking and can last for quite a long time. These days they are often not pressed. Btw, that's why some banh chung you buy you'll find to be much denser than others.

Answer (score -3):

I believe 3-4 days max. Be sure to do the smell and taste test also. Sometimes these kinds of foods are not time-able.